# Obtaining SQL from a SQL Server Profiler trace session

Tags: sql, sql-server-profiler

I have wondered if there is an easy way to obtain the SQL from a SQL Server Profiler trace session into a single SQL script file?

At present I do these steps:

Open SSMS and the database of interest,
Open "Tools | SQL Server Profiler" .. run a trace choosing to filtered to NTUserName Like ... and ticking the "Exclude rows that do not contain values" checkbox.

I perform the step(s) of interest in the application.

I step through each action in the trace table and copy the SQL from the bottom pane showing SQL.

Note: have to avoid "double up" .. i.e. "SQL:BatchStarting" and "SQL:BatchCompleted" .. only want one copy of sql ..

I build up a script of database SQL related to the application action(s).

I know there is File | Save As with a few options ..
Trace File
Trace Template
Trace Table
Trace XML
Trace XML for replay

I have tried creating a Trace Table before and extracting SQL this way ..

Comment: I'd suggest using Extended Events instead of Profiler. Why do you want to see ALL the TSQL ? Perhaps you have an XY problem?? Are you trying to find slow queries?

Comment: Thanks for this comment Mitch. I will have a try  .. I spotted MS doco page as per : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It seems that the solution to the SQL Server Profiler date values in exec statements is to add in the T in the date (manually) ..

Comment: i.e. 
exec P707005CreateMemo '4142541','QRate',NULL,NULL,'2021-06-24T00:00:00'
rather than
exec P707005CreateMemo '4142541','QRate',NULL,NULL,'2021-06-24 00:00:00'
for example ..